# Java - Return an integer array

Tags: java, arrays, string, int, return

In this function, I want to get text in the file then convert it from string to decimal values, by add this text to an array apply some loops and put the result to array of integer. While returning this integer array it gives me an error "cannot find symbol variable integerArray"

```
    int[] inputfile () throws Exception{
     BufferedReader br = null;
       String sCurrentLine;
       String message;
       br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\input.txt"));
       while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
           message=sCurrentLine.toString();
       char[] messageArray=message.toCharArray();

        int[] integerArray = new int[messageArray.length];
           for(int i=0; i<messageArray.length; i++)
               integerArray[i] = (int)messageArray[i];

       }
       return integerArray;
   }
```

How can I solve it?

Update:
I declared variable `integerArray` outside the `while` loop, but it always returns the `null` value, Is there any possible way to return `integerArray` as `int` values? because `Arrays.toString(integerArray)` returns String representation of that array

```
    int[] inputfile () throws Exception{
     BufferedReader br = null;
       String sCurrentLine;
       String message;
       br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\\input.txt"));
       int[] integerArray = null
       while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
           message=sCurrentLine.toString();
       char[] messageArray=message.toCharArray();

        int[] integerArray = new int[messageArray.length];
           for(int i=0; i<messageArray.length; i++)
               integerArray[i] = (int)messageArray[i];

       }
       return integerArray;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int[] integerArray` must be declared before the loop, in order for you to be able to return it after the loop.

```
int[] inputfile () throws Exception{ 
   int[] integerArray = null;
   BufferedReader br = null;
   String sCurrentLine;
   String message;
   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("\input.txt"));
   while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
       message=sCurrentLine.toString();
       char[] messageArray=message.toCharArray();
       integerArray = new int[messageArray.length];
       for(int i=0; i<messageArray.length; i++)
           integerArray[i] = (int)messageArray[i];
   }
   return integerArray;
```

}

Comment: I tried this but the result was "[I@15db9742" , btw my text file contains "Hello"

Comment: @SarahMohamed That just means you are printing the array incorrectly. Use System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inputfile())); to print the output of this method.

Comment: While trying this I found that it returns me a string value, Is there any possible way to return these values in integer?

Comment: @SarahMohamed What do you mean ? Your method returns an integer array.

Comment: Yes, it is. but after using Arrays.toString it returns a String value!

Comment: @SarahMohamed So don't use Arrays.toString()

Answer (score 4):

`integerArray` is a local variable in the while loop , it's inaccessible outside it. Declare it outside the loop

```
int[] integerArray =null ;
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // other code
    integerArray   = new int[messageArray.length];
        // other code
}
```

Comment: The result after applying this is the null value !

Answer (score 4):

Your `integerArray` is inside the `while` loop. Declare it outside the loop and change its value inside it, then it will work.